# Mass replace a column with numbers and add text before them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following column:
https://puu.sh/IVDy8/ed51bddbf7.png

I would like to mass replace those numbers and add text before them:

```
0x8604808b824c4444fe4df3f94850acd584c5ad7d|
```

So for example replace this: `368-4` with `0x8604808b824c4444fe4df3f94850acd584c5ad7d|368-4`

Thank you

Comment: Please do not post links to pictures of code or data. Among other things, readers are unable to cut-and-paste in order to test their code. Also, what does this have to do with regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Try an array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,"0x8604808b824c4444fe4df3f94850acd584c5ad7d|"&A2:A))
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to replace them by using search: `^` and replace with `0x8604808b824c4444fe4df3f94850acd584c5ad7d|`